# Trying Java Card Application On real smart card

Tags: javacard, apdu

I will write an application for smart card with using Java Card Framework.When I finished my application I want to set up to a real smart card and try it.Which equipment I must have?How can I run my codes on a real smart card?I have to provide a connector between my computer and smart card , haven't I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After writing your Java Card application (we call it applet) in your IDE (Such as Eclipse or Netbeans), you have the following steps to communicate with it on a real smart card :

1. Convert the `.java` file to `.class` file
2. Convert the `.class` file to `.cap` file using `converter` tool in the JCDK (Java Card Development Kit)
3. Upload the `.cap` file on the card.
4. Install the uploaded applet.
5. Select your applet on the card using APDU commands
6. Communicate with your applet.

**Step 1 and 2:**

If you want to use a Java Card v2.2.2 or v2.2.1 compatible card, you can simply do step 1 and step 2 by adding [Eclipse-JCDE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-jcde/) plugin and [Java Card Dev Kit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javacard/downloads/javacard-sdk-2043229.html) to *Eclipse* IDE. (A simple great step by step tutorial to use this plugin [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Feclipse-jcde.sourceforge.net%2F&ei=bQlCVfzGHcSZgwTv_4C4Cw&usg=AFQjCNHY5RWN-qh5O1XLU0qzi63ZkLGYhA&sig2=Tnkl8-P1Gi0ZCZdNe5xxTg&bvm=bv.92189499,d.eXY&cad=rja) and [here](http://eclipse-jcde.sourceforge.net/user-guide.htm))

If you want to use a Java Card v3.x compatible card, you can use the newer versions (Mine is 7.3) of *Netbeans* IDE that is contained necessary tools and plugins to do step 1 and step 2,by default.(A simple step by step tutorial, [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javame/java-card.html))

During these steps you set two 5-16 bytes numbers to your application and its package as the applet AID(Identifier) and the package AID

*Note that you can do this steps without any IDE and just using JCDK-s, but is is a little tricky. Moreover, Netbeans IDE added another Java Card simulator to the JCDK simulators (that was named `CREF` and `JCWDE`)*

**Step 3 and 4:**

Connect a smart card reader (FYI it is Smart card writer also) to your computer. Then using [JCManager](https://github.com/martinpaljak/jcManager) tool (Easy use), or the newer tool named [GlobalPlatformPro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro) tool (Easy use, well documented, very comprehensive) you upload the `.cap` file and install the applet separately or simultaneously.
You need your card's authentication keys to have permission to upload and install applet on it.

**Step 5 and 6:**

Normally your smart card reader has a tool to let you communicate with the card (Sending APDU commands and receiving Data and Status Words), but you can also use some free open source tools such as [OpenSC-tool](https://www.opensc-project.org/opensc). Firstly you send a SELECT APDU command to the card with your applet's AID in its data field. And secondly you send other commands to the card.

Notes:

You can use `javax.smartcardio` package in Java or [PySCard](http://pyscard.sourceforge.net/) library in Python, to write your proprietary programs for Step 3,4,5 and 6. (Is is easy for Step 5 and 6, but it is a little hard for steps 3 and 4) ;)

*"APDU" (Application Data Protocol Unit) is the protocol that you use to send[receive] command[response] to[from] the card.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Abraham. If I want to set up my application on real smart card , I have to use FYI device , havent't I?How can I connect my computer to this device?

Comment: @emreturka "FYI" is acronym of "For Your Information".Google the words that they don't look similar to you :)
I was meant Smart card reader is equal with smart card writer. What do you mean by _"How can I connect my computer to this device?"_? A smart card reader is like other removable devices! like your mobile phone! You connect it to your computer using a USB cable or something, install its driver and communicate with it using the described tools. :)

Comment: thank you @MartinPaljak and Abraham.I thought FYI in a Turkish logic. :)